# how to check a value exists in a c++ stl vector and apply a function to every element of the vector?

Tags: c++, vector, iterator, iteration

I have two questions related to the **vector** class of the standard library in C++.

1. How can I check whether a value (let's say of an integer) already exists in a vector?

   What I want in words is as follows: "if the integer already exists in the vector, next one, else add it at the end of the vector."
2. How do I apply a function that holds arguments to every element in the vector? (It seems I can't do that with for_each)

   In words: "for each z element in the vector apply MyAddFn(i,j)"

... or maybe I'm not on the right track with the stl vector sequence container, and I should define my own iterator?

Comment: What exactly do you mean in (2)? What should `MyAddFn(i,j)` be applied to?

Comment: Are you able to use C++11 features with your compiler ? If you are, I advice you to use for_each with a [lambda](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anonymous_function#C.2B.2B) or std::bind. Else, you can deal with [bind1st and bind2nd](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/binder1st.html) but you really should take a look at [boost::foreach](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/doc/html/foreach.html).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1)

`std::find(v.begin(), v.end(), 5) == v.end() // checks that vector<int> v has no value 5.`

2) Use new C++11 std::bind for example, but for real advice i need more context of use MyAddFn.

Comment: Checking inequality with `vector::end()` checks whether the value is **not** stored in the vector! I.e. your expression evaluates to true when the value 5 does exist in the vector.

Answer (score 2):

For 1, use [std::find](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/find/) algorithm. If the element does not exist, it returns the iterator to the end. In that case, add the element.

Answer (score 1):

2nd question. You can use object instead of function:

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

class apply_me
{
  int multiplicator_;
  public:
  apply_me(const int multiplicator) : multiplicator_(multiplicator)
  {};
  int operator ()(const int element) const
  {
    return element*multiplicator_;
  };
};
int main()
{
  std::vector<int> v;
  std::transform(v.begin(), v.end(),v.begin(), apply_me(3));
}
```